# Prevent more slashes in rewritten URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess rule to rewrite my URL

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ app/index.php?app_released=$1&app_name=$2&app_version=$3 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Which rewrites to `app/3-25-2018/name/version` that's fine, but when user tries to put more slashes and some random values after the slash for example `app/3-25-2018/name/version/something/else/here` it should redirect them to my custom 404 page but I'm receiving undefined app_released error by PHP because, it's not able to read the GET variable properly. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the regular expression you use and particularly `(.*)`, which matches all characters including `/`. Instead, supplant `(.*)` with `([^\/]*)` which matches all characters besides `/`.

**Correct Regex:**

```
^app\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$
```

See the above regular expression in action in the following examples:

- matching `app/3-25-2018/name/version` - [here](https://regex101.com/r/mZND01/1/).
- not matching `app/3-25-2018/name/version/something/else/here` - [here](https://regex101.com/r/mZND01/2).

Comment: This worked like a charm, something new I got to learn today. Thank you very much!